# Yii: in a view _view, ho to add a related grid [sortable and searchable]?

Tags: yii

I've Client [1->N] Delivery

In _view of Client I want Delivery related to my client

This is in my ClientController

```
public function actionView($id)
{
    $client = $this->loadModel($id);

    $delivery_provider = new CActiveDataProvider(
      'Delivery',
      array (
          'criteria' => array ( 
              'condition' => 'client_id = :c_id',
              'params' => array (':c_id' => $client->id),
          ), // fine dei criteri
      ) // fine array di definizione cactiveprovider
    ); // fine del CActive provider

    $this->render('view',array(
        'model'=> $client,
        'delivery_provider' => $delivery_provider,
    ));
}
```

Then modules/admin/views/client/_view.php I add my CGridView. ... but ... it's not searchable and not sortable (but pagination works...)

How to proceed ?

Comment: your gridview code is needed to help out here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Delivery is a model it's better to use the `CActiveRecord::search()` instead. This method is automatically generated for you if you used `Gii`.

For searching you have to capture the results of the search form / filters using `$this->setAttributes($_GET['Delivery']);` assuming your inputs have names of the form `Delivery[attribute_name]`.

```
public function actionView($id){
    $client = $this->loadModel($id);

    $delivery = new Delivery('search');
    if(isset($_GET['Delivery']))
        $delivery->setAttributes($_GET['Delivery']);        
    $delivery->client_id=$id;

    $this->render('view',array(
        'model'=> $client,
        'delivery_provider' => $delivery->search(),
    ));
}
```